# How to update value in a file using sed linux

Tags: linux

Need to change value corresponding to "root  soft nproc" from 180000 to 40000. Sample file look like this:
Any easy way to do this in a single line?

```
map   hard   nofile    1000
root    soft    nofile    1000
root    hard   nofile    1010
map   soft    nproc    1200
map   hard   nproc    1200
root    soft    nproc    180000
root    hard   nproc    180000
```

Comment: you are getting downvotes because it is OT for here. Ask on unix.stackexchange or superuser.com - and please format the code part properly...

Comment: This has almost certainly been asked before

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
sed 's/^\(root\s*soft\s*nproc\s*\)180000$/\140000/' file > newfile
```

to replace the value *in place* use option `-i`

```
sed -i 's/^\(root\s*soft\s*nproc\s*\)180000/\140000/' file
```

Syntax is: `sed 's/replace_old/with_new/' file`

- `^` matches the beginning of the line
- `\s*` matches any amount of whitespace characters (spaces and tabs)
- `$` matches the end of the line

The part inside `\(...\)` is captured in a group and replaced by the following part `\140000` where `\1` is a backreference to the captured group.